# How to access change feed in Azure Cosmos DB Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Please forgive me if I am asking this question incorrectly or in a wrong place.

I am trying to understand how to use the change feed for the Cosmos DB.

I do have a Cosmos DB Emulator (a version of a Cosmos DB that is running locally on my machine)

I was able to use and populate it successfully. However, unfortunately, I see no way to view or access the change feed.

Is this even possible to access the change feed on the Cosmos DB Emulator?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no UI for the Change Feed, since the Change Feed is a timeline that could be consuming from multiple points on different ways.

Consuming the Change Feed is always programmatic and done through [any of the available methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/read-change-feed).

Comment: But is it available in Azure Cosmos DB Emulator?

Comment: Yes, you can call the Change Feed REST API on the Emulator endpoint

Comment: On the SDK we use the Emulator to validate our CI pipeline, which includes Change Feed tests.